# In Scala static value initialization does not appear to be happening before the main method is called

Tags: scala

My Scala version:

```
Scala code runner version 2.9.0.1 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
```

Given this code in a file named Static.scala:

```
object Main extends App {
  val x: String = "Hello, World!"
  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(x)
  }
}
```

When I run:

```
scalac Static.scala && scala Main
```

I see:

```
null
```

instead of:

```
Hello, World!
```

I thought that **x** was a static because it was defined in an object, and that it would be initialized prior to the main method being called.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens because of how you used the App trait. The App trait uses the DelayedInit feature which changes how the class body (including field initialization) is executed. The App trait includes a main method which executes the class body after binding the args field to the arguments to the program. Since you have overridden main this initialization is not happening. You should not provide a main method when using the App trait. You should either put the application code directly in the class body or not inherit from the App trait.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
lazy val x = "Hello World"
```

That should give you the results you're expecting.

Comment: It seems that using: def x = "Hello, World" works too.  I'm hoping that the need for lazy only pertains to the main method of an object extending the App trait.  Or do I need to make all values on an object lazy?

Comment: While this is a valid workaround, it's not really a good answer to the problem. It doesn't explain why Tim's program is not behaving as expected and doesn't address this root cause.

Comment: Geoff's answer is the correct one. A lazy val here is a bit of a hack.

Comment: Who are you calling a lazy hack? :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not support to have a `main` method on an object extending `App`. If you do override it, you'd better understand how, exactly, `DelayedInit` works. In particular, objects extending `App` *do not* have static initialization -- that's the whole point of `App`.